ROS2 integer parameter with range
i try create a integer parameter in ros2 which should have a range from 0 to 100. My final goal here is to manipulate this parameter with the rqt reconfigure window through a slider. But i dont find anything about it. So i asked chat gpt and i tried its version:
int min_value = 0;
int max_value = 100;



auto parameter_descriptor = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor();
    parameter_descriptor.type = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterType::PARAMETER_INTEGER;
    parameter_descriptor.description = "description";
    parameter_descriptor.integer_range.emplace_back(min_value);
    parameter_descriptor.integer_range.emplace_back(max_value);
    //parameter_descriptor.integer_range.push_back(max_value);

    node->declare_parameter("yaw", 50, parameter_descriptor);

But that doesnt work, it says that it has a constructor problem for the integer ranges.
Is there a good documentation about this topic or am i totally on the wrong way?
Thank you in advance.

The integer_range member variable is a list (or vector) of rcl_interfaces::msg::IntegerRange.
Usually we have only one range for a given parameter, it can be constructed this way:
auto parameter_descriptor = rcl_interfaces::msg::ParameterDescriptor();
parameter_descriptor.integer_range = {rcl_interfaces::msg::IntegerRange()
                                      .set__from_value(lower)
                                      .set__to_value(upper)
                                      .set__step(step) /* if needed */};


Thank you for your answer. Is there a place of a doc or guide for this? Didnt find one.

I guess I found this in some example or tutorial, you have the same for FloatingPointRange
